# Blurry text on Stack Overflow with Chrome

Tags: bug, status-deferred, stack-overflow, design

There is a bug with Chrome (and probably other WebKit browsers) on the Stack Overflow website.

When trying to open the **More** menu in a tag-related search, the popup is all blurry. This is usually due to the `transform3d` property in a WebKit browser.

I'm using Chrome 78.0.3904.87 on Windows 10.

Here is an image of the bug happening:

[image: blurry popup]

Comment: Are you at a different zoom level other than 100%? We have a known issue filed on our design system for that. https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/392

Comment: Oh, I was. Thank you for pointing it out.@AaronShekey

Comment: Definitely an issue we need to solve though! I'll cross link to this meta post on that issue. Thank you for posting this!

Comment: Hmm the last time I saw this issue posted, the response was "any zoom level except 100% is not supported." Good to see there's work being done on it. Thanks @Aaron!

Comment: When we go full responsive (we're working on eliminating mobile-specific views but it's a large volume of work) all of this should be easier to improve. As we migrate to Stack overall, this is getting better and better but won't be 100% any time soon.